# Pairwise t test with 3 vectors

Tags: r

So I have 3 vectors and need to do a pairwise t test on them.

Here is the code I have so far

```
> x1=c(6.5,15.5,15.2,10.8,3.7,11.2)
> x2=c(11.2,10.5,6.8,5.1,5.7)
> x3=c(5.9,6.8,4.1,10.4)
> pairwise.t.test(x1,x2,x3,p.adj="bonferroni")
```

It just keeps giving me errors. Im guessing the data has to be in some other form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pairwise.t.test` needs a grouping factor or 'g'.  In this case, the individual `vector`s can be converted to a named `list` with `mget`, then reshape it to a two column data.frame with `stack` and then use `pairwise.t.test`

```
with(stack(mget(paste0("x", 1:3))), 
     pairwise.t.test(values, ind, p.adj = 'bonferroni'))
#   Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD 

#data:  values and ind 

#   x1   x2  
#x2 0.79 -   
#x3 0.44 1.00
```